# Puppet unable to find environment

Tags: puppet, puppet-enterprise

I have a simple Puppet environment, just started with one master and one agent.

I am getting following error when I do `puppet module list` from my agent. I run `puppet agent -t`  it is not even going to my site.pp and test.pp.

I am not sure if I am missing anything in the Puppet configurations.

```
 puppet module list
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/environments.rb:38:in `get!': Could not find a directory environment named 'test' anywhere in the path: /etc/puppet/environments. Does the directory exist? (Puppet::Environments::EnvironmentNotFound)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/application.rb:365:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:146:in `run'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:92:in `execute'
        from /usr/bin/puppet:8
```

Here is my Puppet master puppet.conf

```
    [main]
    # The Puppet log directory.
    # The default value is '$vardir/log'.
    logdir = /var/log/puppet

    # Where Puppet PID files are kept.
    # The default value is '$vardir/run'.
    rundir = /var/run/puppet

    # Where SSL certificates are kept.
    # The default value is '$confdir/ssl'.
    ssldir = $vardir/ssl
    dns_alt_names = cssdb-poc-01.cisco.com cssdb-poc-01

[master]
    server = cssdb-poc-01.cisco.com
    certname = cssdb-poc-01.cisco.com
    dns_alt_names = cssdb-poc-01.cisco.com cssdb-poc-01
    environmentpath = /etc/puppet/environments
    environment = test

[agent]
    # The file in which puppetd stores a list of the classes
    # associated with the retrieved configuratiion.  Can be loaded in
    # the separate ``puppet`` executable using the ``--loadclasses``
    # option.
    # The default value is '$confdir/classes.txt'.
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt

    # Where puppetd caches the local configuration.  An
    # extension indicating the cache format is added automatically.
    # The default value is '$confdir/localconfig'.
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
~
```

Here is the directory structure on puppet master.

```
    [root@cssdb-poc-01 test]# tree /etc/puppet/environments/
/etc/puppet/environments/
├── example_env
│   ├── manifests
│   ├── modules
│   └── README.environment
├── production
└── test
    ├── environment.conf
    ├── manifests
    │   └── site.pp
    └── modules
        └── cassandra
            ├── manifests
            └── test.pp
```

Here is the my puppet agent puppet.conf

```
cat /etc/puppet/puppet.conf
[main]
    # The Puppet log directory.
    # The default value is '$vardir/log'.
    logdir = /var/log/puppet

    # Where Puppet PID files are kept.
    # The default value is '$vardir/run'.
    rundir = /var/run/puppet

    # Where SSL certificates are kept.
    # The default value is '$confdir/ssl'.
    ssldir = $vardir/ssl

[main]
    server=cssdb-poc-01.cisco.com
    environmentpath = /etc/puppet/environments
    environment = test

[agent]
    # The file in which puppetd stores a list of the classes
    # associated with the retrieved configuratiion.  Can be loaded in
    # the separate ``puppet`` executable using the ``--loadclasses``
    # option.
    # The default value is '$confdir/classes.txt'.
    classfile = $vardir/classes.txt

    # Where puppetd caches the local configuration.  An
    # extension indicating the cache format is added automatically.
    # The default value is '$confdir/localconfig'.
    localconfig = $vardir/localconfig
```

Comment: Modules are usually only installed on the master. Listing them is not suposed to work on the agent side.

Comment: I am not able to see even on the master 

puppet module list
/etc/puppet/modules (no modules installed)
/usr/share/puppet/modules (no modules installed)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with my environment.conf file.

```
[root@cssdb-poc-01 templates]# cat /tmp/environment.conf
modulepath = /etc/puppet/environments/test/modules:$basemodulepath
manifest = manifests
```

I removed it from environment directory and it started working, not `puppet modules list` but `puppet agent -t`

@Frank you are right `puppet modules list` will not work on agent nodes.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Custom modules will not show up in `puppet modules list` output. It lists modules with metadata, typically installed from the Forge using `puppet module install`.

On the agent, it is normal to have no local environments to search for modules (or install them).

Comment: Try debugging things with a standalone master. Stop the master service and run `puppet master --no-daemonize --verbose --debug`, see what is going on.